# How to include an FXML file in another one in jar?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am trying to use `<fx:include source="abcd.fxml"/>` tag but I get `Base location is undefined` error when launching the application.

If a set the location of FXMLLoader this time it doesn't work in jar files because when a resource is in jar file it's URL is meaningless (because a jar file is a kind of a zip file).

Is there a way to use this include tag even if I deploy my application as a jar file?

Comment: *"If a set the location of FXMLLoader this time it doesn't work in jar files because when a resource is in jar file it's URL is meaningless"*. This isn't true. If you set things up correctly, you will get a resource URL with a `jar:` scheme. Typically you just use `getClass().getResource()` on an appropriate class. You should post some code showing what the issue is.

Comment: Probably you're loading the fxml passing a `InputStream` instead of a `URL`. `InputStream` does not contain any information about the data source which makes resolving relative paths impossible...

Comment: @James_D I get a url like "{....}.jar!/abcd.fxml".

Comment: @ozgur Yes, exactly. That's what you want.

Comment: You should post some code showing what the problem is, if you can't solve it setting the FXML loader's location via a URL from `getClass().getResource()`.